# Data copied from a row in ListView1 is not appearing in ListView2

Tags: listview, vb6

This code should copy over any selected item from ListView1 to ListView2. It's copying over one item, but the subitems on the index 1 and 2 appear blank.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ListView2.ListItems.Add = ListView1.SelectedItem

    ListView2.SelectedItem.SubItems(2) = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(2)
    ListView2.SelectedItem.SubItems(1) = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Visual Basic 6.0, and not VB.NET?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
ListView2.ListItems.Add ListView1.SelectedItem
```

adds a copy of the selected item from `ListView1` to `ListView2`.

However, it does not *select* the new item. Therefore, the next two lines of code:

```
ListView2.SelectedItem.SubItems(2) = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(2)
ListView2.SelectedItem.SubItems(1) = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)
```

don't do what you were hoping, because `ListView2.SelectedItem` is *not* the item that you just added.

To make the code work correctly, write it so that you keep a reference to the item you add in a variable, and then set the properties of that item:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim li As ListItem
    Set li = ListView2.ListItems.Add ListView1.SelectedItem

    li.SubItems(2) = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(2)
    li.SubItems(1) = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)

End Sub
```

And please name your controls something more descriptive than the default `Command1`/`ListView2`!